# Why WordPress doesn't show pictures when I upload them in a new post?

Tags: images

I have a serious problem.

When I write a new post in the edit window, I try to upload a picture via the media upload button, and it just doesn't add them.

I just cant upload any type on media at all to my posts.
How can I fix it?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because as-written it is a **user support** question that would be better asked at the [WordPress.org support forums](http://wordpress.org/support).

Answer (score 0):

You need to click on the `Insert into Post` button (located at the bottom right corner of the media upload page) to insert your images in your post, after you upload it.